# Networkx: create a directed scale free graph with a given number of communities

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to work with Networkx to create a graph that is composed of a fixed number of communities in which there are different probabilities for adding edges for nodes inside a given community and adding edges for nodes between different communities. I have looked at the generator for directed [scale_free_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.directed.scale_free_graph.html#networkx.generators.directed.scale_free_graph). Here is an example of how to create three disconnected graphs using it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
N_tot = 100 # total number of nodes
pos_frac = 0.1 # fraction of positive nodes
neg_frac = 0.1 # fraction of negative nodes
N_p = int(pos_frac*N_tot) # number of positive nodes
N_n = int(neg_frac*N_tot) # number of negative nodes
N_0 = int(N_tot - (N_p + N_n)) # number of neutral nodes
G1 = nx.scale_free_graph(N_p, seed=3)
G2 = nx.scale_free_graph(N_n, seed=2)
G3 = nx.scale_free_graph(N_0, seed=1)
nx.set_node_attributes(G1,"blue","color")
nx.set_node_attributes(G2,"red","color")
nx.set_node_attributes(G3,"green","color")
G1adj=nx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_matrix(G1,weight=None)
G2adj=nx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_matrix(G2,weight=None)
G3adj=nx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_matrix(G3,weight=None)
mappingG2 = {}
for i in range(G2.number_of_nodes()):
    mappingG2[i]=i+G1.number_of_nodes()
G2 = nx.relabel_nodes(G2, mappingG2)
mappingG3 = {}
for i in range(G3.number_of_nodes()):
    mappingG3[i]=i+G1.number_of_nodes()+G2.number_of_nodes()
G3 = nx.relabel_nodes(G3, mappingG3)
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,3)
ax[0].matshow(G1adj)
ax[1].matshow(G2adj)
ax[2].matshow(G3adj)
```

Someone has an idea of how to create the links between those three graphs while maintaining the scale free property of the whole graph?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to join three scale-free graphs and obtain a single scale-free graph?

Comment: Yes, but that the properties of the probabilities of attachment within each communities may be different from the probabilities of attachment between communities... does it make sense?

Comment: What is the probability of attachment within each community?

Comment: For now I use the default inside each community (alpha=0.41, beta=0.54, gamma=0.05, delta_in=0.2, delta_out=0)

Comment: This is more a mathematical question, you'll hardly find an answer here on SO...

Comment: This is an ill-determined problem because there is no universally agreed measure of scale-freeness. If there were a measure, you could randomly rewire some edges between modules, check if the resulting graph was (still) scale-free, and repeat the process until you had the a graph with the desired scale-freeness. But unless **you** define **your** desired measure of scale-freeness, it is impossible to decide if any algorithm (let alone any implementation) returns the desired result.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0501169.pdf) discusses some of the issues in rigorously defining what it means to be scale-free. They also make an attempt at a definition themselves but note that this is not a universally acknowledged solution.

Comment: Did you specifically want a variation of the Bollobás et al model?  Or would any model that produces power-law type graphs suffice?